# Can we initialize state equal to 0 in redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my code I have initialized the `state=0` in the reducer. I don't know how it is turning to 1. Below is my code:

```
export default function (state=0, action={}) {

 var newState;
 switch (action.type) {
    case 'SHOWLOADINGBAR':

        newState = state + 1;

        break;
    case 'HIDELOADINGBAR':

        newState = state > 0 ? state - 1 : 0;

        break;
    case 'RESETLOADINGBAR':

        newState = 0;

        break;
    default:

        return state;
}
return newState;
}
```

In an ideal condition it should return `state=0`, but sometimes behaves anonymously. It is returning 1 and sometimes 5. I have used redux logger for debugging, but all the alteration is happening before the action.

Below is the screen shot:
[image]

Comment: you put console logs in SHOWLOADINGBAR and HIDELOADINGBAR and they are definitely never called?

Comment: yeah i'm attaching the screenshot

Comment: and if you log `action.type` it's what you expect (always defined) and your SHOWLOADINGBAR and HIDELOADINGBAR are also defined correctly as strings (not undefined from a typo/partial refactor)? And you are not directly modifying store state in your app?

Comment: Random guess here:  Search your code for some place you are accidentally doing `if (state = 5)` instead of `if (state === 5)`

Comment: @Barndon : hi I cheked it it was not that case :(

Comment: try changing `var newState` to `let newState` or remove the newState variable completely. It may be some scoping issues.